# org.testng.TestNGException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset while trying to debug/run a test in IntellIJ idea CE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, testng

I have been working on a project, where I am able to successfully run the unit tests via `mvn clean install` command.

However, when I try to run a unit test individually by clicking on the arrow beside `@Test` annotation, I am getting connection reset error.

Local setup -

- *IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Community Edition)* for he development process.
- MacOS Ventura 13.3
- zulu-8 jdk (1.8.0_362) macos-aarch64
- TestNG version - 6.14.3

Any clues on this, and how can it be resolved? Thanks

Stack trace -

```
org.testng.TestNGException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:327)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:476)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:470)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1423)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1329)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:444)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:415)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1505)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1305)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1271)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:264)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1160)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1044)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:958)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:642)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:326)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
... 3 more

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by upgrading the testNG version to 7.0.0 in the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version in pom file, for me it's worked when updated to the version **7.9.0**.